# Terraform How to make v4_cidr_blocks

Tags: terraform

Sorry, I am new to terraform.
I use yandex provider, but i think it is similar with aws.
I need to substitute "v4_cidr_blocks" when creating a "security group" in the ip/mask format
I got ip through "data source" - "data.yandex_compute_instance.instance1.network_interface.0.ip_address". How to add a subnet mask to it and substitute it in "v4_cidr_blocks"?
Perhaps write the data source to a variable and apply some kind of text function?

I get 192.168.10.2 through "data source", but I need to substitute v4_cidr_blocks - 192.168.10.2/32

Comment: Please add the code you have to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text concatenation to add the subnet mask (i.e. /32) when you use the value. For example:

```
v4_cidr_blocks = ["${data.yandex_compute_instance.instance1.network_interface.0.ip_address}/32"]
```

or if you want to make it more flexible:

```
#variables.tf
variable "subnet_mask" { default = "/32" } 

#main.tf
v4_cidr_blocks = ["${data.yandex_compute_instance.instance1.network_interface.0.ip_address}${var.subnet_mask}"]
```